# How to write out the first two columns of a txt file in pse script?

Tags: powershell

I've got a text file which contains lines like this:

```
ADUALI 4751 random name
ADWXLI 4757 random name
```

I need a script that writes out the first two columns of the file. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way :

```
gc c:\temp\test.txt | %{ $line=$_.split(" ");write-host  $line[0] $line[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
gc file.txt | Foreach-Object {$_.Split()[0..1]}
```